# Диапазон селектов CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Как я могу указать диапазон выбора? Например, у меня есть 100 дивов с аттрибутом timestamp. Мне нужно показать элементы, timestamp которых больше 5, но меньше 20, а остальные скрыть. Как это сделать?

Answer (score -2):

Сделал простой скрипт в связке с moment.js:

```
let styles = '',
        start = this.picker.getAttribute('range').split(':')[0], //unix
        end = this.picker.getAttribute('range').split(':')[1]; //unix

    start = moment.unix(start);
    end = moment.unix(end);

    let days = n(end.diff(start, 'days')) + 1,
        temp = start.clone(), times = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < days; i++) {
        styles += `:not([timestamp="${temp.format('YYYY/MM/DD')}"])`;
        temp.add(1, 'day');
    }

    this.styleObject.innerHTML = `div${styles} {display: none;}
        div.component-item-list${styles} {display: none;}`;
```